# Node-Red: working with CSV Node

Tags: node.js, node-red

I am sending a csv file:

```
A1,A2,A3,A4
B1,B2,B3,B3
```

to a csv node with 4 columns (A,B,C,D).

I am able to see the first csv record as a JS Object, but I wasn't able to access the rest of the records.

the csv node output look like this:

```
(Object) { "A": "A1", "B": "A2", "C": "A3", "D": "A4\r\nB1" }
```

How Can I work with the csv node to access each record?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The csv node currently expects each input message to contain only record as it expects to only output one record at a time.

The simplest way to fix this is to insert a function node before the csv node to break multi-line messages into separate messages:

```
var lines = msg.payload.split("\n");
var messages = [];

for (var i=0; i<lines.length; i++) {
   //deep copy the orginal message to ensure we don't loose any other fields
   var tmp = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(msg));
   //the trim deals with dos line endings
   tmp.payload = lines[i].trim();
   messages.push(tmp);
}
return [messages];
```

Comment: thanks @hardliib! Does this also apply to an array of csv objects that were nested into an array? I thought this was what the csv node expected but it does not seem to like an array of csv objects so I think I need to split them apart!